# Conditional Join in Spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to join two `DataFrame` with condition.

I have two dataframe A and B.

A contains id,m_cd and c_cd columns
B contains m_cd,c_cd and record columns

Conditions are -

- If m_cd is null then join c_cd of A with B
- If m_cd is not null then join m_cd of A with B

we can use "`when`" and "`otherwise`()" in `withcolumn`() method of dataframe, so is there any way to do this for the case of join in dataframe.

I have already done this using `Union`.But wanted to know if there any other option available.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the "when" / "otherwise" in the join condition:

```
case class Foo(m_cd: Option[Int], c_cd: Option[Int])
val dfA = spark.createDataset(Array(
    Foo(Some(1), Some(2)),
    Foo(Some(2), Some(3)),
    Foo(None: Option[Int], Some(4))
))


val dfB = spark.createDataset(Array(
    Foo(Some(1), Some(5)),
    Foo(Some(2), Some(6)),
    Foo(Some(10), Some(4))
))

val joinCondition = when($"a.m_cd".isNull, $"a.c_cd"===$"b.c_cd")
    .otherwise($"a.m_cd"===$"b.m_cd")

dfA.as('a).join(dfB.as('b), joinCondition).show
```

It might still be more readable to use the union, though.

Comment: If I want to add multiple condition like If, else if, else of java and scala in this condition (val joinCondition = when($"a.m_cd".isNull, $"a.c_cd"===$"b.c_cd").otherwise($"a.m_cd"===$"b.m_cd")) 

Is it possible??

Comment: Hi @Avijit. You can chain multiple "when". "when" can act as the "if" and as the "else if", so you can do "when(condition1, value1).when(cond2, val2).otherwise(default)"

Comment: could you share a union based solution?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is trying to do it in PySpark here's the syntax

```
join_condition = when(df1.azure_resourcegroup.startswith('a_string'),df1.some_field == df2.somefield)\
    .otherwise((df1.servicename == df2.type) &
    (df1.resourcegroup == df2.esource_group) &
    (df1.subscriptionguid == df2.subscription_id))
df1 = df1.join(df2,join_condition,how='left')
```