# Spark conditionally merging 2 dataframes in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 Dataframes that I need to merge a single column together conditionally.  Whenever there is a null value in the id column, i need to reference another DF to get the value from there.

```
df1.show()
+-----+---+----+-----+
|group|cat|  id|value|
+-----+---+----+-----+
|    X|  A|   1| 20.0|
|    X|  A|   2| 20.0|
|    X|  A|null| 55.0|
|    X|  B|   1| 20.0|
|    X|  B|null| 55.0|
|    Y|  A|   3| 20.0|
|    Y|  A|   4| 20.0|
|    Y|  A|null| 55.0|
|    Y|  B|   4| 20.0|
|    Y|  B|null| 55.0|
+-----+---+----+-----+
df2.show()
+---+-------+
|cat|     id|
+---+-------+
|  A|1 2 3 4|
|  B|    1 4|
+---+-------+
```

With my final desired result being:

```
+-----+---+-------+-----+
|group|cat|     id|value|
+-----+---+-------+-----+
|    X|  A|      1| 20.0|
|    X|  A|      2| 20.0|
|    X|  A|1 2 3 4| 55.0|
|    X|  B|      1| 20.0|
|    X|  B|    1 4| 55.0|
|    Y|  A|      3| 20.0|
|    Y|  A|      4| 20.0|
|    Y|  A|1 2 3 4| 55.0|
|    Y|  B|      4| 20.0|
|    Y|  B|    1 4| 55.0|
+-----+---+-------+-----+
```

I've tried something similar to another answer here ([Conditional Join in Spark DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39417209/conditional-join-in-spark-dataframe))

```
val joinCondition = when($"a.id".isNull && $"a.cat" === "b.cat", $"a.id"===$"b.id")
    .otherwise($"a.id")

df1.as('a).join(df2.as('b), joinCondition).show
```

but always end up with an empty dataframe.

Any thoughts on the correct join condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the two data frames, and then update `id` with `id` from `df2` using `coalesce` function:

```
(df1.join(df2.withColumnRenamed("id", "id2"), Seq("cat"), "left")
    .withColumn("id", coalesce($"id", $"id2")).drop("id2").show)

+---+-----+-------+-----+
|cat|group|     id|value|
+---+-----+-------+-----+
|  A|    X|      1| 20.0|
|  A|    X|      2| 20.0|
|  A|    X|1 2 3 4| 55.0|
|  B|    X|      1| 20.0|
|  B|    X|    1 4| 55.0|
|  A|    Y|      3| 20.0|
|  A|    Y|      4| 20.0|
|  A|    Y|1 2 3 4| 55.0|
|  B|    Y|      4| 20.0|
|  B|    Y|    1 4| 55.0|
+---+-----+-------+-----+
```

Comment: THANK YOU!  I knew I was overthinking it, just couldn't get there!