# How to join two dataset with OR condition using spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Java here and my current datasets looks like this:

**dataset d1** (where column c1 has both int and string type dataset):
c1, c2, c3
12, ab, a
xy, ah, ab
19, a,  ad
a,  b,  c

**dataset d2**
c1, c2, c3
12, ab, a
10, ah, ab
19, a,  xy
1,  b,  c

Now I want to join two dataset with OR condition like:

```
d1.col(c1).equalTo(d2.col(c1)).or(d1.col(c1).equalTo(d2.col(c3)))
```

I have tried the above join and it works with smaller dataset but when we do it for bigger dataset like 8billion X 1 million it runs forever. I am not sure what it happens. Any leads?

I have also tried following things:

```
when(condition, value1).otherwise(value2)
```

But it also didn't worked out. I have also tried googling it but no luck. Also seen this stack overflow post but not working for me.
[Conditional Join in Spark DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39417209/conditional-join-in-spark-dataframe)

Comment: Take a look at [Optimize Spark job that has to calculate each to each entry similarity and output top N similar items for each](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50088548) - this is exactly the same category of problems.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for sharing the post but still it doesn't answer the question that how can I join two datasets on 1 to many column using OR key.